# Laravel route pointing outside project directory

Tags: laravel

So I am new to Laravel.
I have a project named Blog created using Composer and placed inside WWW of Wamp server.

I am using the following routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

Here is the code I am using in layout.blade.php in views folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Once I click Home, it takes me to http://localhost
How can I make sure it takes me to http://localhost/blog/public

Also, how to hide the "public" folder from url?

I did change the .env file to this

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/blog/public/
```

thoughts? where am I going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to set the APP_URL.  You just need to set the public folder as the root folder in your Wamp server.

Comment: This is a server configuration issue, not a Laravel one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign name to routes

```
Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
})->name('contact');
```

And use the global function route in your blade

```
<li><a href="{{route('contact')}}">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you Fabián Montero Rodríguez

Answer (score 1):

When you click

```
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

the effective url in apache is assumed to be http://localhost/

in order to redirect properly you'll need to use either named routes `route('name')` or use `url()` helper,

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
```

or if using named route, then you'll need to first define a named route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

<li><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
```

Also, if you want to hide public from your url then either you can install your project in such a way that your public folder is the root folder of your servers. 
Alternatively, you can move your index.php and .htaccess from `/public' folder to your apps root directory. Also make sure to edit index.php so that it points to correct autoload.php and app.php

change this

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

If your js and css throw 404, then use `asset()` helper with public

```
<script src="{{ asset('public') }}/js/main.js">
```